# Scoped forward declaration

Tags: c, struct, forward-declaration

How can I have a struct declaration for each function, like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct additionalVariables;

struct container {
    int am;
    int bm;

    struct additionVariables *variables;
};

void foo(void) {
    struct container myContainer;

    struct additionalVariables {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    myContainer.variables = malloc(sizeof(struct additionVariables));

    myContainer.variables->x = 5;
    myContainer.variables->y = 6;

    free(myContainer.variables);
}

void bar(void) {
    struct container myContainer;

    struct additionalVariables {
        char a;
        int b;
        int x;
    };

    myContainer.variables = malloc(sizeof(struct additionVariables));

    myContainer.variables->a = 5;
    myContainer.variables->b = 6;
    myContainer.variables->x = 7;

    free(myContainer.variables);
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
    bar();

    return 0;
}
```

I would prefer not to have to cast. Different additionVariables structs must be able to have the same names, for example both foo and bar need a property for x.

Comment: I think you're looking for a `union`.

Comment: Use a `void *` for `variables` member.

Comment: Can't use a union since I need to access it as myContainer.variables.x (so it would have to use C11 anonymous inheritance) but both need a property called x so that wouldn't work. My conditions are very specific, I'm not sure it's possible. Looking for closest answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to make local versions of the `container` structure.

```
void foo(void) {
    struct {
        int am;
        int bm;
        struct additionVariables {
            int x, y;
        } *variables;
    } myContainer;

    myContainer.variables = malloc(sizeof(struct additionVariables));
    myContainer.variables->x = 5;
    myContainer.variables->y = 6;

    free(myContainer.variables);
}
```

Then you can have the `container` structure declared with a void pointer if you need to pass it around.

```
struct container {
    int am;
    int bm;
    void *variables;
};
```

You will however still need to make a cast if you want to pass the object to some other function:

```
DoSomeThingWithContainer((struct container *)&myContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can** make `container` visible in your main but `additionalVariables` obviously can't be.
I Split it to several files and it compiles (and more importantly links) ok.

**main.c**

```
#include "foobar.h"

int main(void) {
    foo();
    bar();

    return 0;
}
```

**foobar.h**

```
void foo(void);
void bar(void);

struct additionalVariables;

struct container {
    int am;
    int bm;

    struct additionalVariables* variables;
};
```

**foo.c**

```
#include "foobar.h"

#include <stdlib.h>

struct additionalVariables {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void foo(void) {
    struct container myContainer;

    myContainer.variables = (additionalVariables*)malloc(sizeof(struct additionalVariables));

    myContainer.variables->x = 5;
    myContainer.variables->y = 6;

    free(myContainer.variables);
}
```

**bar.c**

```
#include "foobar.h"

#include <stdlib.h>

struct additionalVariables {
    int x;
    char a;
    int b;
};

void bar(void) {
    struct container myContainer;

    myContainer.variables = (additionalVariables*)malloc(sizeof(struct additionalVariables));

    myContainer.variables->a = 5;
    myContainer.variables->b = 6;
    myContainer.variables->x = 7;

    free(myContainer.variables);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve the problem as presented:

```
struct container {
    int am;
    int bm;
};
```

You have not explained exactly why you needed the abstract pointer. So, I removed it.

```
void foo(void) {
    struct mycontainer {
        struct container base;
        int x;
        int y;
    } myContainer;

    myContainer.x = 5;
    myContainer.y = 6;
}
```

Here, `foo()` declares its local version of the container, adding additional fields. The address of `myContainer.base` can be passed to any function that wants a `struct container *`, and it would have the same address as a pointer to `myContainer`. Since we aren't dealing with pointers anymore, there is no need to call `malloc()` or `free()`.

```
void bar(void) {
    struct mycontainer {
        struct container base;
        char a;
        int b;
        int x;
    } myContainer;

    myContainer.a = 5;
    myContainer.b = 6;
    myContainer.x = 7;
}
```

`bar()` can create its own version also.

```
int main(void) {
    foo();
    bar();

    return 0;
}
```

I have a feeling, however, that what you really want is [dynamic dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17622474/315052).

Answer (score 0):

Declare the struct externally with all of the names you need available in all branches:

```
struct additionalVariables {
    int x;
};

struct container {
    int am;
    int bm;
    struct additionalVariables *variables;
};
```

Then extend it within each function by placing the original as the first element of the greater struct:

```
void foo(void) {
    struct container myContainer;

    struct additionalVariablesFoo {
        struct additionalVariables base;
        int y;
    };

    myContainer.variables = malloc(sizeof(struct additionVariablesFoo));

    myContainer.variables.x = 5;
    (struct AdditionalVariablesFoo *)&(myContainer.variables)->y = 6;

    free(myContainer.variables);
}
```

Since it's always OK to cast down to the type of the first element, you'll be able to access the `x` field outside the function without a cast, at the cost of needing the cast to get at the `y` field within the function at init-time (obviously you don't need this cast either if you simply init it through a temporary variable of type `struct AdditionalVariablesFoo *`). Outside the function the extended object will be treated as having the type of its first element, the base where the shared names are declared.