# How to implement class and method in C? (e.g. Linux Kernel)

Tags: c, linux, class, operating-system, kernel

I am watching Linux kernel code, and found some C codes that behaves like classes in objected oriented programming.

Example:

```
const struct sched_class fair_sched_class = {
    .next           = &idle_sched_class,
    .enqueue_task       = enqueue_task_fair,
    .dequeue_task       = dequeue_task_fair,
    .yield_task     = yield_task_fair,
    .yield_to_task      = yield_to_task_fair,

    .check_preempt_curr = check_preempt_wakeup,

    .pick_next_task     = pick_next_task_fair,
    .put_prev_task      = put_prev_task_fair,
};
```

Let's suppose some functions like `enqueue_task_fair` are already implemented above.
How does above code work? What does the `.` operator do within the initialization body?
Could you give me an example how to use `struct sched_class` in the main function?

Comment: [Dynamic method dispatching in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17621544/315052).

Comment: Then, what does `.` operator within the struct phrase does?  Does it refer to the member variable of the struct?  Example: ```.next           = &idle_sched_class```