# Parameterizing type definition at compile time

Tags: c, matrix, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, static-memory-allocation

What is a good way to define this graph data structure:

```c
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short isExists : 1;
    WEIGHT_TYPE weight;
} Weight;

typedef struct
{
    Weight adjacencyMatrix[VERTICES_NUM][VERTICES_NUM];
    VERTEX_TYPE vertices[VERTICES_NUM];
} Graph;
```

using a value for `VERTICES_NUM` defined at compile time?

I am looking for a better solution than defining `VERTICES_NUM` before including the `.h` file that contains the above, and I do not want to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid any usage of dynamic allocation here." Why? How large are these structures, potentially? Having to recompile the code for different sizes seems clunky, if not ridiculous, in 2024. You can't declare a C structure with a size that's a parameter. The compiler needs to know the size *in advance*. A runtime size is a *dynamic* size.

Comment: You want a dynamic structure, but you don't want dynamic allocation....

Comment: PSA: Using bitfields is probably not a good plan here.

Comment: @tadman It is not necessarily about the size, but I want to be able to somehow pass macros every time I include the file (for the vertex type or weight type) .

Comment: Can you edit the question to include an example of how this might be used?

Comment: I don't think there's anything better than `Init(&g, VERTICES_NUM, WEIGHT_TYPE)`

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean? my issue is not defining the constants, rather than passing them as I need.

Comment: Types are not first-class objects in C, you can't pass `char` as a function parameter.

Comment: Functions that need to be able to deal with arrays of varying type, like `qsort()` take the size of each element as a parameter. So you can pass `sizeof WEIGHT_TYPE`.

Comment: Than how could I pass the type every time I include the file? I'm trying to avoid void pointers and dynamic allocatiion.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the type? What will you do with it in the function?

Comment: Does it have to be C? I think C++ templates resolve this kind of problem more naturally for you. In C, you would have to use some kind of hairy macro mechanism.

Comment: I just need to initialize the graph with a given type of vertices info, and given number of vertices.

Comment: If the `Init` needs the type, why can't it just use the macro `WEIGHT_TYPE` itself?

Comment: @jxh it does have to be C. is there a way to pass the macros using a function?

Comment: No, there isn't. Types are simply not runtime values, they're only used at compile time. There's no such thing as dynamic typing.

Comment: @Barmar this is a header file, I might include it many times in many contexts so I can't define a constant type for all usages

Comment: @Liorv No, you would use a macro to create the kind of Weight and Graph based on  WEIGHT_TYPE. It would be something like `GRAPH_TYPE(WEIGHT_TYPE, VERTICES_NUM) g;`

Comment: @Liorv You can't include it many times, because you'll get a redefinition error.

Comment: Let me clarify my question, I isn't meant to be dynamic typing thing, I still want static types, but I want to define the types every time I include the file, and not in the header file itself so it can vary in different usages.

Comment: @Barmar I mean including it in different files...

Comment: Right, you are trying to treat your header file like a parameterized code generator.

Comment: As long as you use the same definition of `WEIGHT_TYPE` and `VERTICES_NUM` when you compile `Init.c`, things will work.

Comment: @jxh exactly, can I do that without using `#define VERTICES_NUM 10` before the include instruction?

Comment: Re “Let me clarify my question”: Clarify your question by editing the post.

Comment: You can do it on the compilation line: `gcc Init.c -DVERTICES_NUM=10 -DWEIGHT_TYPE=char`

Comment: I really think you want C++.

Comment: @jxh it is not really my choice... I'm only allowed to use C.

Comment: @Barmar I need these constants to be defined in the code itself

Comment: *"can I do that without using #define VERTICES_NUM 10 before the include instruction? "* That's your only option, and not a bad one.

Comment: If you don't want to have to repeat them in each source file, put the `#define` statements in another header file, which you include at the beginning of `Graph.h`. Then you can edit it to have different values.

Comment: I'm not the only one working on this project, I need this graph library to be easy to use by other people who don't know how it is implemented... so I want that they will be able to decide how many vertices to use and what type to use without having to know the exact name of the constant I use, or know where they have to modify the define instruction.

Comment: Then the use of that `#define` constant needs to be part of the documentation.  There's precedence for that in library functions.

Comment: I know I can document it and make it clear, but if feels more like a workaround...

Comment: One other *possible* way to to define the struct with pointers, declare a large global array, and allocate space for the struct out of the global array.  As for the weight type, if there are a small number of known possible types you can use a `union` for them.

Comment: I can't use union for the weight since it can be any either primitive or user define type

Comment: Then you have no choice.  The user needs to supply a header with the appropriate `#define` constants.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's a hefty edit, and one that removes some relevant data such a parameterizing the types.

Comment: @dbush: I do not see what you mean. The edit focuses on parameterizing the types, removing the cruft that is not about parameterizing the types, and puts parameterizing the types into the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would first approach the problem with a macro that will define the types for you.

```
#define DEFINE_GRAPH(NAME, WEIGHT_TYPE, VERTEX_TYPE, VERTICES_NUM) \
        DEFINE_WEIGHT_TYPE(NAME, WEIGHT_TYPE); \
        DEFINE_GRAPH_TYPE(NAME, VERTEX_TYPE, VERTICES_NUM)

#define DEFINE_WEIGHT_TYPE(NAME, WEIGHT_TYPE) \
        typedef struct { \
            unsigned short isExists : 1; \
            WEIGHT_TYPE weight; \
        } WEIGHT(NAME)

#define DEFINE_GRAPH_TYPE(NAME, VERTEX_TYPE, VERTICES_NUM) \
        typedef struct { \
            WEIGHT(NAME) adjacencyMatrix[VERTICES_NUM][VERTICES_NUM]; \
            VERTEX_TYPE vertices[VERTICES_NUM]; \
        } GRAPH(NAME)

#define WEIGHT(NAME) NAME ## _Weight
#define GRAPH(NAME) NAME ## _Graph
```

Now, a user could do something like:

```
DEFINE_GRAPH(Test, char, float, 10);
```

And in their code, they would use the data structure like this:

```
int main () {
    GRAPH(Test) g;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Hiding definitions in such macros is a terrible idea. It makes programs so difficult to read and maintain. If you have 4-5 in one project from different developers your programming life becomes a misery.

Comment: Can I do that without the name parameter?

Comment: Not safely. Different parameter values result in different types, so they should have different names.

Comment: @jxh and then after 6 months try to remember how to access it

Comment: @jxh That's right but what if I know for sure that I have only graph in each file?

Comment: What ever simplicity you are trying to achieve by removing that name, I assure you will cause problems for you.

Comment: @gulpr Systems programmers are generally fine with this coding method. Reference: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/queue.7.html

Comment: Also, What if I wanted to write a general library of function (like join edge and other graph functions), how could I do that using this header file?

Comment: @Liorv If you are trying to achieve an abstract interface over the code, you could try to emulate polymorphism. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17621544/315052

Comment: @Liorv Or you can define the operation functions as macros, like in the queue implementation I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @jxh it is different case as queue user does not see the implementation only a very high level interface

Comment: @gulpr You wouldn't feel that way if your code using queue wasn't working.

Comment: @jxh, thanks for the solution and the explanation. I was wondering whether I could somehow 'save' the `VERTICES_NUM` inside the graph structure (without using `const` variable outside of the structure itself or pre-defining it)?

Comment: @Liorv It is implicitly defined by the vertices array. You could do `sizeof(g.vertices)/sizeof(g.vertices[0])` to get the number of elements in the array.

Comment: That's right, I just wanted to know whether there's a way to define it inside the `DEFINE_GRAP` but I guess calculating it through the array is indeed the best possible way.

Answer (score 1):

Using macros is not a good idea. Perhaps you can try something like this.

The advantage is that you can easily work with multiple graphs of different sizes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int WEIGHT_TYPE;
typedef int VERTEX_TYPE;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned short isExists : 1;
    WEIGHT_TYPE weight;
} Weight;

typedef struct
{
    int verticesNum;
    VERTEX_TYPE* vertices;
    Weight* adjacencyMatrix;
} Graph;

Graph newGraph(int n, VERTEX_TYPE* v, Weight* a ) {
    Graph g;
    g.verticesNum = n;
    g.vertices = v;
    g.adjacencyMatrix = a;
    return g;
}

VERTEX_TYPE* getVertex(Graph* g, int n) {
    return g->vertices + n;
}

Weight* getAdjacency(Graph* g, int x, int y) {
    return g->adjacencyMatrix + y * g->verticesNum + x;
}

void setAdjacency(Graph* g, int x, int y, int exists, WEIGHT_TYPE weight) {
    Weight* w = g->adjacencyMatrix + y * g->verticesNum + x;
    w->isExists = exists;
    w->weight = weight;
}

void clearGraph(Graph* g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < g->verticesNum; ++i) {
        g->vertices[i] = 0;        
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < g->verticesNum; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < g->verticesNum; ++x) {
            Weight* w = getAdjacency(g, x, y);
            w->isExists = 0;        
            w->weight = 0;
        }
    }
}

void printAdjacency(Graph* g) {
    for (int y = 0; y < g->verticesNum; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < g->verticesNum; ++x) {
            Weight* w = getAdjacency(g, x, y);
            if (w->isExists)
                printf("%d ", w->weight);
            else
                printf(". ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    // Stack allocated data
    int n = 10;
    Weight adjacency[n*n];
    VERTEX_TYPE vertices[n];
    
    // Stack allocated graph that makes use of the stack allocated data above
    Graph g = newGraph(n, vertices, adjacency);
    clearGraph(&g);
    setAdjacency(&g,1,1,1,3);
    printAdjacency(&g);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can define these constants before including the .h file, but
> I'm looking for a better solution.

Usually two methods are used.

1. Create `.h` file with common definitions like your sizes and include this file when needed.
2. Use compiler command line options. gcc has `-D` option (`-DVERTICES_NUM=10`)