# Function definition in C struct?

Tags: c, struct, constructor

I have a C code I need to understand. There is a

```
typedef struct someStruct {
    int i; 
    char c; 
    someStruct() {
        i = 0;
        c = 'c';
    }
    someStruct(char inpChar) {
        i = 1;
        c = inpChar;
    }
} t_someStruct;
```

(The code doesn't really make sense or serve a purpose, I know. I just simplified it.)
So there is this structure and it has two members (int i and char c). The interesting part is that it has basically two constructors, which is a new concept to me. 
It works normally, but can we write constructors for structures? I couldn't find anything on Google, maybe I am not searching right.

Comment: It's most likely C++ code, not C code.

Comment: in C++, a struct is a type of Class and that code will work but not in C. If you want something similar in C - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052443/c-function-inside-struct

Comment: If it doesn't compile on your C compiler, chances are it is not valid C.

Comment: "I have a C code" competes with "it has basically two constructors". thats paradox as in C code isn't anything provided, whats called constructor, or behaves after that concept.;)

Comment: That was my point exactly, no constructors in C. It might be a C++ code, that makes sense. As source code I only have some headers which are written in C style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is not valid C code (i.e. valid [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29)) code but it is valid C++ (i.e. [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14)) code.

In C++, a `struct` is like a `class` except that all members are by default `public`; see e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class).

Answer (score 3):

## There are no constructors in C.

This code is most probably in C++.
In C++, a `struct` is actually similar to a `class`, hence you *can* define constructors for structs in C++.

Try to compile your code in gcc. You'll get a

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘someStruct’
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between C and C++ is that C++ supports class but C does not. In C++ struct is a special class so the above code will work in C++ but not in C.