# Generating a random number without random function

Tags: c, random

i need to generate a random number without using "random" function so i found this code which give me mlliseconds in system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>

int main()
{
struct timeb tmb;

ftime(&tmb);
printf("tmb.time     = %ld (seconds)\n", tmb.time);
printf("tmb.millitm  = %d (mlliseconds)\n", tmb.millitm);

return 0;
}
```

it was working good until i tried to use it inside struct in this way :

```
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
struct Num{
struct timeb tmb;
ftime(&tmp);    
};
int main()
{

return 0;
}
```

its giving an error at {ftime}.
any help ?

Comment: "an error"? And the actual error is?

Comment: [Error] expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'ftime'

Comment: Ah, just saw it: Why are you trying to call the function from the declaration of the struct (i.e. outside a function)? Because ... well ... why would that work?

Comment: its homework where we need to generate a random number inside struct and after that to use it in main ( i cant use get_time or random functions)

Comment: Well, this is C, struct's are datatypes and contain no code. So if the prompt is "do this inside a struct", the answer is "The language cannot do this".

Comment: you say that there is no way to use this code out of main function ?

Comment: the prompt is " do not use this inside main function"

Comment: Well, given that `int my_random() {...}` seems fine. No need for the struct.

Comment: thaaaaaaanks :)

Comment: you can not have a function inside a struct ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052443/c-function-inside-struct )

Comment: Which book are you reading? You can't safely learn C without *some* kind of guide, and clearly your current guide isn't working for you. I suggest K&R2E; do the exercises as you come across them (and don't move on 'til they're complete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ftime(&tmp);` is an example of a postfix expression as specified by [C11/6.5.2](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.2) (fourth line down):

> ```
>         postfix-expression:
>                  primary-expression
>                  postfix-expression [ expression ]
>                  postfix-expression ( argument-expression-listopt )
>                  postfix-expression . identifier
>                  postfix-expression -> identifier
>                  postfix-expression ++
>                  postfix-expression --
>                  ( type-name ) { initializer-list }
>                  ( type-name ) { initializer-list , }
>          argument-expression-list:
>                assignment-expression
>                argument-expression-list , assignment-expression
> ```

The C standard reference specifies the grammar for the struct specifier you've used in [C11/6.7.2.1](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.7.2.1), and clearly your example violates that grammar, as there are no possibilities for a *postfix-expression* here:

> ```
>         struct-or-union-specifier:
>                  struct-or-union identifieropt { struct-declaration-list }
>                  struct-or-union identifier
>         struct-or-union:
>                 struct
>                 union
>         struct-declaration-list:
>                 struct-declaration
>                 struct-declaration-list struct-declaration
>         struct-declaration:
>                 specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-listopt ;
>                 static_assert-declaration
>         specifier-qualifier-list:
>                 type-specifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
>                 type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
>         struct-declarator-list:
>                 struct-declarator
>                 struct-declarator-list , struct-declarator
>         struct-declarator:
>                 declarator
>                 declaratoropt : constant-expression
> ```

The syntactic structure of C isn't too difficult to learn; it's taught fairly well within most books. My suggestion is that you find a new guide, as the semantics of C will prove *extremely challenging* if you struggle with the syntax. As I wrote in the comments for your question:

> I suggest K&R2E; do the exercises as you come across them (and don't move on 'til they're complete).

If you struggle with some words from your textbook or an exercise, please post a question about whatever it is that confuses you.