# Problems with understanding code: function in struct

Tags: c, struct

I got the following code from here: [C - function inside struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052443/c-function-inside-struct). I've been looking at it for an hour but I just don't understand it. Starting with the very first line: I know

```
typedef struct client_t client_t;
```

But how does the additional **pno* work, what is it doing? Why is *next* never used?  Where does **self* come from?

```
typedef struct client_t client_t, *pno;
struct client_t
{
        pid_t pid;
        char password[TAM_MAX]; // -> 50 chars
        pno next;

        pno (*AddClient)(client_t *);    
};

pno client_t_AddClient(client_t *self) { /* code */ }

int main()
{

    client_t client;
    client.AddClient = client_t_AddClient; // probably really done in some init fn

    //code ..

    client.AddClient(&client);

}
```

Comment: As the comments and answer to the linked question say, you don't have a function in a struct (that's not legal in C). You have a function pointer in a struct.

Answer (score 1):

`pno` is a typedef to pointer to `struct client_t`.

```
typedef struct client_t client_t, *pno;
```

means the same as:

```
typedef struct client_t client_t;
typedef struct client_t *pno;
```

So `client_t` means the same as `struct client_t` and `pno` means the same as `struct client_t *`. Let's substitute them in your code.

```
struct client_t 
{
        pid_t pid;
        char password[TAM_MAX]; // -> 50 chars
        struct client_t *next;
        struct client_t *(*AddClient)(struct client_t *);    
};

struct client_t *client_t_AddClient(client_t *self) { /* code */ }

int main()
{

    struct client_t client;
    client.AddClient = client_t_AddClient; // probably really done in some init fn

    //code ..

    client.AddClient(&client);

}
```

So `struct client_t` has a member called `next` that is a pointer to `struct client_t` - classic linked list. The `struct client_t *(*AddClient)(struct client_t *);` is a function pointer declaration, that takes a pointer to `struct client_t` and returns a pointer to `struct client_t` - judging from the name, it adds next client to the current item, but I don't know what does it return because it hasn't been explained.

I discourage using `typedef`s to hide pointers - it makes your code less readable.

> But how does the additional *pno work, what is it doing?

The additional `*pno` defines additional identifier `pno` to be a typedef  to `struct client_t *` type.

> Why is next never used?

Because you did not show where it's used. (?) It's impossible to answer that question without knowing the context.

> Where does *self come from?

It's the identifier given the argument in the function `client_t_AddClient` definition. I believe it "comes" from writer of this code - he decided to name the argument to this function as "self". I guess it means it refers to the current object, as to mimic `self` keyword for example from python.

Comment: `typedef` of pointers [is debatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750178/10077).