# Translating wrapped function like struct of C/C++.bt (Binary Template) to Java 8

Tags: c++, struct, java-8

Sorry, I have almost 20 years without touching `C/C++`.

I Would like translate [this](https://github.com/ydkhatri/APFS_010/blob/master/apfs.010.bt) code to Java 8, I found this [Reference Manual](https://download.sweetscape.com/010edrefmanual11.0.pdf).
I was reading that in this [link](https://sweetscape.com/010editor/).

You can read...

*Binary Templates are easy to write and look similar to C/C++ structs except they may contain if, for, or while statements as well as functions or complex expressions.*

*Powerful enough to parse almost any binary file format.*

*Can be set to run automatically when files are opened.*

*Templates may be shared and a list of templates for download is available in our Template Repository.*

I begins and in the line `2063` I found  (sorry, I could only translate, sad 4 lines :(! ).

```
APFS apfs(0);
```

I was reading [C - function inside struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17052443/811293) but looks, so many different!

Reviewing I jump to the line `1994`, *it looks like a structure with a function call, instead of having attributes!!!*.

```
typedef struct APFS(uint64 apfs_offset) {
  DefineApfsContainer(apfs_offset);  
} ;
```

Inmediatly you can see in the line `1998`

```
void DefineApfsContainer(uint64 apfs_offset) {
  Apfs_Offset = apfs_offset;
  FSeek(Apfs_Offset);
  if (!CheckApfsAndSetBlockSize()) {
    Printf("\nError, starting point not an APFS container superblock. Set the 'Apfs_Offset' variable to correct value!");
    Exit(1);
  }
  
  obj csb;//container super block in block zero
  
  
  SeekBlock(csb.body.xp_desc_base);
  CheckpointDesc cp(csb.body.xp_desc_blocks);
  
  //SeekBlock(csb.body.xp_data_base);
  //obj checkpoint_data_nx[csb.body.xp_data_blocks] <optimize=false>;
  
  // Checkpoint processing
  local uint i = 0;
  local uint64 max_xid = 0;
  local uint64 max_xid_block_pos = 0;
  SeekBlock(csb.body.xp_desc_base);
  local uint64 base_pos = FTell();
  local uint64 pos = 0;
  
  for (i=0; i< csb.body.xp_desc_blocks; ++i) { // assuming cont. blocks
    if (cp.checkpoint_desc_nx[i].hdr.type == obj_type_container_superblock) {
      if (cp.checkpoint_desc_nx[i].hdr.xid >= max_xid) {
        // validate it 
        pos = base_pos + (i * Block_Size);
        if (fletcher64(pos, Block_Size) == 0) {
          max_xid = cp.checkpoint_desc_nx[i].hdr.xid;
          max_xid_block_pos = pos;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (max_xid > csb.hdr.xid)
    Printf("\nFound newer xid=%Lu @ offset 0x%Lu. Using this Container superblock.", max_xid, pos);
  
  FSeek(pos);
  obj valid_csb;
  BookmarkVolumes(valid_csb);
  if (valid_csb.body.efi_jumpstart) {
    SeekBlock(valid_csb.body.efi_jumpstart);
    obj efi_info;
  }
  /*if (valid_csb.body.keylocker_block_count) {
    SeekBlock(valid_csb.body.keylocker_paddr);
    obj keybag; // This is encrypted!
  }*/
}
```

I need to understand what does that (I don't mean the code, but the way of coding), in order to translate.
**How should I understand this code (a function as a structure or a structure from a function)?**

The nugget of subject.
**How should I translate it to Java?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn’t quite translate to Java because it’s code-generating code, ie. code that some tool uses to generate the actual C-like code (in a nutshell), or code for a bespoke virtual machine that then implements the data extraction and data packing. The idiomatic way to do this in Java without writing a stand-alone tool would be by attributes and similar mechanisms, introspection, and runtime code generation, repurposing Java syntax to express the same idea. You could attempt to do manual translation - that would grow the code a whole lot. The binary template concept is very powerful - leads to very concise code that would otherwise be tedious to implement.

I’d say that a manual translation will be more work than writing the translator, because you’ll be debugging all the manual mistakes till the cows come home. The syntax is limited enough so that a parser and translator written in Java will be about the same number of lines as a “straightforward” Java implementation of the binary template.

You may look at the tool this template is written for and see if the tool offers a way of translating the template. If the tool is open source then you already have a parser :)